# How to perform a Long Click event on a button where onclick is disabled in Android?

Tags: android

Consider an Activity where button named "Scan", is disabled as soon as Bluetooth device gets connected, for preventing further scanning.

```
mScan.setEnabled(false);
```

But as soon as it is connected I need the same button mScan to show some dialog which has additional functionalities when it is **Long Pressed**.

The problem is as I disabled the mScan button I can't perform onLongClick function.

How Can I achieve the same?

Seeking your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom `OnTouchListener`:

```
long lastDown;
long lastDuration;

 public class YourOnTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener
{
    public YourOnTouchListener(some parameters) {
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

            return true;


        } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {

            lastDuration = System.currentTimeMillis() - lastDown;


            if (lastDuration > the duration you want) {
            //do what you want here
                return true;
            }
        return false;

    }


}
```

Then you can control what you want to do according to a duration, and it works with a `OnClickListener` as well.

Comment: Don't extend, implements

Comment: Sorry man couldn't understand. As I am just new to this function. Do you have any examples? More over what should be the lastDown parameter should be?

Comment: lastDown and lastDuration are class variables. The OnTouchListener allow you to manage many kind of events like when you put your finger on the screen and then when you release it. So it give more possibilities than the OnClickListener. What you can do is save the current time when tu user put his finger and make the difference with the time when he releases the finger. then according to your duration your are free to do what you want. This could work in association with OnClickListener and OnLongClickListener. I provided you a basic example with no process inside but you can find some on SO